# angular child scope can not refer to parent

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to angular and try to figure out how scope works.

I assume that the child scope will inherit scope from parent. see [angularjs wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

> In AngularJS, a child scope normally prototypically inherits from its parent scope.

So I create some simple test code in [pluncker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GS0ET1)

But when I change scope variable from child scope, it does **NOT** reflect change to the parent scope?

**Why is it? Did I do something wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scopes inherit a property from its parent only when that property **is missing**. In your code, when you don't type anything yet, the property is missing and inherited from parent scope, but as you start typing, the property is created on the child scope as **a separate property**. After creating a property on the child scope, `ng-model` keeps updating this property on the child scope.

In case you need to bind to parent scope's properties, you could try `$parent.out_var1`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$parent.out_var1">
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/22cqZH5wTeoGo7L3lug0?p=preview)

Comment: Do you mean the ng-model directive declare this property again, so it is redefined in the child scope?

Comment: @xiaopang: ng-model creates the property because it does not exist on the child scope. In this case, both the parent scope and child scope have this property, but they are different.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the answer. but another question is how could I refer to the parent property from child scope then? I know from controller, I can refer it , but how could I refer it from view?

Comment: @xiaopang: You should be make sure you understand the difference between objects (like Objects, Arrays, Functions) and primitive values (like Strings, Integers, Booleans) in scope inheritance. If you would use an object's property instead of a primitive (e.g. if you used `someObj.out_var1` instead of `out_var1`) things would look a lot different. Read the wiki really carefully. See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ulPaUqqGwya5kdlCoybv?p=preview)**.